# How to compute $\lim_{\left( {x,y,z} \right) \to \left( {0,0,0} \right)} \frac{{{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2}}}{{x + y + z}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How do I solve the following limit:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y,z} \right) \to \left( {0,0,0} \right)} \frac{{{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2}}}{{x + y + z}}$$

Comment: Express $(x, y, z)$ in spherical coordinates.

Comment: What makes you think there is a limit?

Answer (score 2):

The limit does not exist.
Here is how I reached the conclusion.

Let
$y = ax$
and
$z = bx$.

Then
$ \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}
=\frac{x^2+a^2x^2+b^2x^2}{x+ax+bx}
=x\frac{1+a^2+b^2}{1+a+b}
$,
so it looks like
this $\to 0$
as
$\max(|x|, |y|, |z|)
\to 0
$.

However,
looking at this,
if $y = -x$
and
$z = x^2$,
then
$ \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}
=\frac{x^2+x^2+x^4}{x-x+x^2}
=\frac{2x^2+x^4}{x^2}
=2+x^2
\to 2
$.

This suggests trying
$y = -x$
and
$z = ax^2$.
Then
$ \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x+y+z}
=\frac{x^2+x^2+a^2x^4}{x-x+ax^2}
=\frac{2x^2+a^2x^4}{ax^2}
=\frac{2}{a}+ax^2
\to \frac{2}{a}
$.

Therefore,
the limit does not exist,
since it has
different values
depending on $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For $(x,y,z) \ne (0,0,0),$ the numerator is $>0$ while the denominator vanishes along an entire plane through $(0,0,0).$ Such a function can never have a limit at $(0,0,0)$ - even if you insist $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)$ outside the zero set of the denominator.

Comment: Indeed. If you set $x = z$ and $y = -2x + \epsilon$ and vary $\epsilon$ slightly, then the numerator hardly changes (if $\epsilon$ is a lot smaller in absolute value than $x, y, z$), but the denominator comes as close to $0$ as you like.

Comment: Right. In fact here $\inf f= -\infty, \sup f = \infty $ in any deleted neighborhood of the origin minus the zero set of $x+y+z.$

Answer (score 1):

First notice this change of variables:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x = R\cos \varphi \cos \theta \\
y = R\sin \varphi \cos \theta \\
z = R\sin \theta 
\end{array} \right.$$

which is the well-known spherical coordinates. The you can write

$$\begin{array}{l}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\left( {x,y,z} \right) \to \left( {0,0,0} \right)} \frac{{{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2}}}{{x + y + z}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to 0} \frac{{{R^2}}}{{R\left( {\cos \varphi \cos \theta  + \sin \varphi \cos \theta  + \sin \theta } \right)}}\\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{R \to 0} \frac{R}{{\left( {\cos \varphi  + \sin \varphi } \right)\cos \theta  + \sin \theta }}
\end{array}$$

Now try two different paths (lines) like

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\theta  = \frac{\pi }{2}\\
\varphi  = 0
\end{array} \right.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,,\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\theta  = 0\\
\varphi  = \frac{{3\pi }}{4}
\end{array} \right.$$

you will see that the limit won't be the same on these two paths. Hence, you can conclude that it does not exist.